# Get list of all ENS domains stored in a wallet address using Ethers.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethers.js

How can I get a list of all ENS names stored in a specific wallet using Ethers.js?
for example; I want to get all the ENS names in this address;

"0x8f635716982B836c4eB47e2F5c7B007Dde278F99"

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to do it using a provider like QuickNode.
You can simply use `lookupAddress` method of ethers.js

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
(async () => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("YOUR_URL_HERE");
  const names = await provider.lookupAddress("YOUR_WALLET_ADDRESS_HERE");
  console.log(names);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't fetch it directly from the smart contract. (etherjs)

But, You cloud done it using the ENS official sub-graph.

Go here: https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/ensdomains/ens

And try this query

```
{
  domains(first: 100, where: { owner: "0xa729addefe1fa7bce87053ed55d55edddd13de60" }) {
    name
    owner {
      id
    }
  }
}
```